# click functionality in selenium webelement for IE fails

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer

We were trying to submit the process in application through selenium. But it is not able to click in IE. For our requirement, we need to execute the script in Internet explorer.

I'm new to selenium script. Could You please provide inputs?

Below code:

```
public void clickOnElement(final String name) {
     final By elementName = getProperties().getSearchCriteria(name);
     final WebElement element = findClickableElement(elementName);
     element.click();
}
```

Comment: Element not found Exception? Have you used XPATH as locator?

Comment: XPATH also one of the parameter we were passing. we have id,css,name and xpath.

Comment: In case if you have used XPATH for the element which is throwing not found exception, then the reason is XPATH which works in chrome/firefox might not work in IE... I have faced this issues few times

Comment: Ok. Then what way we have achieve this click functionality in IE?

Comment: Its not with the click functionality, it is with respect to identifying the element. Try using id's or some other locators for that element.

Comment: Able to click by xpath or id by first time. But after testcase is trying to click the element, it is not able to do. It is failing in element.click()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147426/discussion-between-santhosh-kumar-and-shailu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try the steps mentioned below and then try to run the automation script for IE Browser.**

1. For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target 
   the computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE.
2. For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is 
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet 
   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the 
   FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Inside this key, create a DWORD value named 
   iexplore.exe with the value of 0.)
3. Protected mode settings are the same for all zones
4. Enhanced Protected Mode is disabled.